# Is there a way to republish an old version of an Android app to the Play Store without being able to build a new APK?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

Trying to help a friend -

They accidentally released a really bad build to the Play Store and disabled it, but now many users are stuck with it cause they can't downgrade. I've read in other questions that you can just update the versionCode and rebuild the APK and release a new version that way, but he's in a situation where he can't build the APK from scratch anymore.

Is there *any* other way to switch an app in the store back to an old version of the APK without actually building an APK from source?

Answer (score 1):

Rebuilding new APK and releasing a new version is not an option in this scenario.
Ask your friend to try following below steps:

1. Rebuild project in its previous state with higher version number (must be higher than 
   all previously submitted versions).
2. Resubmit.

Found this on [Android Developer Console page](https://developer.android.com/distribute/console)

> Note that **rollbacks aren’t supported** due to the app versioning requirements of the >Android platform. **If you need to rollback, consider launching a previous APK with a new >version number.** However, this practice should be used only as a last resort, as users >will lose access to new features and your old app may not be forward-compatible with >your server changes or data formats, so be sure to run alpha and beta tests of your >updates.